# PHP REST API not receiving body content after HOST change

Tags: php, rest, host

we have changed our Host and are having some trouble.
When we post a request to the server, it doesn't seem to receive the body content of the request.

The request is being issued and the URL parameters are being read correctly.

```
$information is NULL, even though the request has been sent with body content.
//Receive Request Body
$information = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);
```

It has been working on the old host, that's why we are confused. Did anyone experience the same issue and knows how to go about this issue?

Comment: I can't think of any way that the hosting service would change how this works.

Comment: What does libcurl have to do with this? Is the client sending the request with curl?

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` show?

Comment: Yes, the client is sending the request with libcurl.
Sure, give me 1 minute to echo the var dump.

Comment: All I can think of is that the new hosting service might have an IDS that's blocking this content. But blocking JSON to an API is not a good idea.

Comment: Oh wow, var_dump seems to show the right data, but why is $information NULL then?

Comment: Use `json_last_error()` to get the error reason.

Comment: json_last_error() is not showing any error. This is what var_dump echos out: `string(271) "{"software_version","6.3.0","config_version":"6.3.0","acc_id":557,"unique_address":"H24W-nWEn-nezx-qdod-SUkt","hwid":"","vm_server_name":"MAIN","vm_name":"VM","status":"Offline","username":"User","password":"Pass","region":"NA","list_name":"Test"}"`

Comment: That string is only 247 characters long, I wonder what the other 24 characters are. That's probably relevant to the problem.

Comment: Whoops, my bad for not stating that I changed some values manually

Comment: Or is that because you redacted the username and password.

Comment: Damnit, I feel embarassed.. The issue is that I was too sleepy and not looking at what I was writing.. `"software_version","6.3.0"` is invalid syntax...  Thanks a lot for taking your time and helping me! :)

Comment: If `json_decode()` returns `null` then `json_last_error()` and `json_last_error_msg()` should return something.

Comment: Make sure you're using a JSON library to create the JSON at the client end, then you won't have problems like that.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the suggestion. Should be easy, since I have one on the server side.

Comment: Maybe I used the function wrong? I inserted json_last_error() without var_dump or echo before it.

Comment: It just returns the error code, you have to echo it. `echo json_last_error_msg();`

Comment: My bad, I thought it echos on its own.